# Difference Between ExecuteSQL and ExecuteSQLRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to understand the difference between the two processors `ExecuteSQL` and `ExecuteSQLRecord` (V1.8 onwards). Is there something extra which the later provides and `ExecuteSQL` doesn't? One thing I have already seen is that ExecuteSQL doesn't mantain "state". Does  `ExecuteSQLRecord` take care of it?

Comment: Thank you I had been wondering of the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two processors share a LOT of code, the only real difference is that ExecuteSQL only outputs the results as Avro, whereas ExecuteSQLRecord can output the results using any RecordSetWriter into its associated format, such as Avro, JSON, CSV, XML, etc.