# what is the difference between executesql and executesqlrecord

Tags: apache-nifi

In Nifi, why do we have **executesql** if we have **executesqlrecord**?

Is there any difference between *executesql* and *executesqlrecord* other than that the first produces only **Avro** and the second gives more options for the produced **flowfiles**?

Is there any performance preferences between them? for example executesql executes in a batch mode and the executesqlrecord executes in a row-by-row mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between ExecuteSQL and ExecuteSQLRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518557/difference-between-executesql-and-executesqlrecord)

Comment: This says there is no difference other than that the ExecuteSQL is limited to generate only Avro, but it does not answer: why then we have it, if we have ExecuteSQLRecord?

Comment: ExecuteSQL was created first. ExecuteSQLRecord was added later with extra flexability. ExecuteSQL wasnt removed. That's why we have both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both processors are very similar. See here [Difference Between ExecuteSQL and ExecuteSQLRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518557/difference-between-executesql-and-executesqlrecord)

1. ExecuteSQL was created first.
2. ExecuteSQLRecord was added later after the Records feature was introduced to NiFi.
3. ExecuteSQL was never removed. It provides a user with options & maintains backwards compatability for people still using ExecuteSQL.